# Unable to open socket to /dev/tty.usbmodemxxxxx on OS X 10.8

Tags: c, macos, usb, arduino

I have a piece of custom Arduino hardware that is hooked up to my computer over USB.  I wrote a simple test socket program to simply send a test single and receive a response.  This works on both Windows and Linux, but not on OSX.

If I open a terminal app like ZTerm or screen I'm able to connect just fine on the Mac, just not through the socket using /dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx.  I can connect over /dev/cu.usbmodemxxxx and it appears to send correctly in the program, but never receives any data.  I have verified the hardware is not receiving the data over the /dev/cu socket.

The code is fairly straight forward c code.

```
socket = open("/dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_ASYNC);
if (socket < 0) { // error here };

// -- edit -- added baud rate change.
struct termios term;
memset(&term, 0, sizeof(struct termios));
cfmakeraw(&term);

cfsetspeed(&term, COM_SPD);
term.c_cflag = CREAD | CLOCAL;
term.c_cflag |= CS8;

term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
term.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

ioctl(socket, TIOCSETA, &term);

// -- /edit --
char str[1024] = { 0x30, 0x08, ... };
write(socket, str, 8);

sleep(2);

char data[64] = { 0x0 };
int len = 0;
ioctl(socket, data, &len);

read(socket, data, len);

// output data.
```

For simplicity I've left out all the error handling and debugging code.

Is there any reason why I cannot connect over tty?  And also why would I be able to connect over cu but never receive any responses from the hardware?

Additionally if I connect to the device using Z-Term and then send a response using /dev/cu in the program, the hardware receives the data and ZTerm receives the correct response, but the program doesn't receive anything.

Is there something special you need to do on OS X to connect to the tty device?

Comment: Perhaps `sudo` your program?

Comment: yeah I already tried sudo and that did not work.